# Bootstrap Collapse Element: Show on first click -> next time do nothing

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

i have two div's which are collapsed and i want to show them when i click on an image.
When the div's are shown and i click on the image again i don't ant to get the div's collapsed again.

I added the collapse class to the element

```
<div class="container collapse">'
```

Then i added the onclick event to the image to run my Java Script function

```
onclick="playSoundAndShowSpoiler('http://www.url.to/soundfile.mp3',this)
```

The function itself looks like

```
<script>            
        function playSoundAndShowSpoiler(url, obj)
        {
            new Audio(url).play();

            var collapseElementList = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.collapse'))
            var collapseList = collapseElementList.map(function (collapseEl) {
            return new bootstrap.Collapse(collapseEl)
            })
        }
    </script>
```

The snipped regarding the collapse part is from the Bootstrap Docs and i wonder how i have to change it so that the Collapse Part only run once and do not collapse the div's on a second click on the image.

Any kind of help is appreciated!

best ragrds
Rolf

P.S. For reference - this is the affected site: https://schmellerling.de/indexnew.php

Answer (score 0):

**Plain JavaScript**

```
// better off with targeting element by its ID.
document.getElementById("container").addEventListener("click", function() {
    playSoundAndShowSpoiler();
}, {once: true});
```

Useful link: https://caniuse.com/once-event-listener

**Jquery approach:**

Once the DOM is loaded, bind the handler to the element with `one` method.

```
function playSoundAndShowSpoiler(url, obj) {
    new Audio(url).play();

    var collapseElementList = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.collapse'))
    var collapseList = collapseElementList.map(function (collapseEl) {
    return new bootstrap.Collapse(collapseEl)
    })
}

$("container").one('click', function() {
    playSoundAndShowSpoiler();
});
```

**Note: The event handler function is only run ONCE for each element.**

Useful link: https://api.jquery.com/one/

Comment: 1. this is jQuery specific, OP isn't using jQuery 2. [please do not use, recommend or link to w3schools](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280478/why-not-w3schools-com)

Comment: The Plain Java Script approach looks interesting. In my case my function does two things and i want one to happen evry time the image is clicked, so this will break my functionality.

I tried to split the function in two seperate functions but i was not able to call two functions with one onclick event.